# c/c++ for loop performance on linux

Tags: c++, arrays

i have some doubt regarding the performance of for looping construct in C

considering the below code is executed n a linux 64bit system, which version would give better performance:

```
for (i = 0;i<10000;i++)
{
    for (j = 0;j<10000;j++)
    {
        x[i][j] = 0;
    }
}
```

or

```
for (i = 0;i<10000;i++)
{
    for (j = 0;j<10000;j++)
    {
        x[j][i] = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Seriously? Why don't you try for yourself? I am seriously thinking about slapping `performance` tag on it so everyone will know on sight the questions is nonsense.

Comment: 1) Profile, and you'll know the answer if you can even measure the runtime. 2) Use memset, that's optimized for this use case.

Answer (score 3):

The real question you should be asking is this: Are matrices in C++ laid out in row major or column major order? To which the answer is **row major**.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing nested for loops in both case.

Since the loop is in another loop, the time will take

O(log2(n)^2)

So basically, if 2 loops are nested, independent on the actions inside of it it will take n*n = n^2. If the loops are not nested, it will take n+n = 2n

Answer (score 0):

You can find out for yourself:

```
/* Example 1 */

time_t start = clock();
for (i = 0;i<10000;i++)
{
    for (j = 0;j<10000;j++)
    {
        x[i][j] = 0;
    }
}
float t = (float)(clock() - start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC; 
printf("%f\n", t);

/* Example 2 */

start = clock();
for (i = 0;i<10000;i++)
{
    for (j = 0;j<10000;j++)
    {
        x[j][i] = 0;
    }
}
t = (float)(clock() - start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC; 
printf("%f\n", t);
```